# How do I install gcc 4.7?

Tags: software-installation, gcc

I wish to install gcc 4.7 so that I can use some c++11 features.

I downloaded the source, ran `./configure` and was told I needed GMP. Downloaded the code for that, hit `./configure` and was told I needed m4. But I already have m4 (least that is what synamptic tells me).

What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have tried and it has worked for me: http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/ Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can try this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test) for installing gcc 4.7. Do note that it has packages only for 12.04 and not for 11.10.

Run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7
```

Or, if you prefer a graphical way of installing a PPA, take a look at [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).

Comment: If you want to replace gcc 4.6 and make gcc 4.7 the default gcc compiler, you have to follow [these](http://superuser.com/a/394811/121972) instructions

Comment: I didn't have `add-apt-repository` installed, I fixed this with `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`

Comment: Then do this http://askubuntu.com/questions/269257/how-to-activate-gcc-4-7-version and repeat the same steps for G++.

Comment: This is an old answer, we are now in ubuntu 17.04, shoudl it perhaps be edited, or does it only work for 12.04 still?

Comment: If you would be so kind to let me take advantage of your Compiz / CCSM skills, I'm stumped and posted a question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1348326/307523 TIA

Answer (score 30):

**NOTE!!**

You also most likely need to take care of **g++-4.7**

So the full commands list will be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7 g++-4.7
```

Also, don't forget to update-alternatives, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182027/how-to-use-gcc-4-7-in-place-of-4-6-ubuntu-12-04)

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.7 
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

This is confirmed to work in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: g++ is a subset of gcc, no?

Comment: He and many others might be unaware, as I was. The thing is that in various distributions, once you install gcc, g++ got's installed automatically, with this ppa it's not the case and you need to install both separately.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer, the other one is incomplete I think...

Comment: Then do this http://askubuntu.com/questions/269257/how-to-activate-gcc-4-7-version and repeat the same steps for G++.

Comment: Easiest way I think to activate gcc `sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 /usr/bin/gcc`

Answer (score 0):

Search the build directory for `config.log` files, and search those for the error message. That should give some clues.

BTW, if you don't need 4.7 precisely, you could try installing the gcc-snapshot package. That should have the features you need. It doesn't get installed in the standard place though, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Where does it get installed?

Comment: The full file-list (for 64-bit 12.10) is here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/gcc-snapshot/filelist

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete guide of how to build from sources gcc-4.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits:

http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/04/13/building-gcc-4-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: That guide makes the second common mistake given at http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC, making life far more complicated than it needs to be