# A question about "add-apt-repository"(gcc 4.7 or bumblebee)

Tags: ppa, gcc, c++, bumblebee

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my notebook and I use C++. I want to use C++11, so I want to upgrade my `gcc` to `gcc-4.7`. I ran these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7  
sudo apt-get install g++-4.7
```

But when I ran `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7`, it can find `gcc-4.7-base` but not `gcc-4.7`. And when I ran `sudo apt-get install g++-4.7`, it could not find anything.

Today, I wanted to install `bumblebee` so I started to run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
sudo reboot
```

But when I ran `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`, it told me the packages couldn't be found.

I used the Ubuntu 12.04 methods described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113291/installing-gcc-4-7) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation).

What can I do?

Comment: is `sudo apt-get update` is completing successfully? and what version of ubuntu are you using. I suspect you are using a old version for which the packages are not listed.

Comment: you can see in this ppa gcc 4.7 only exist for `precise` not in `oneric` https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test?field.series_filter=oneiric

Comment: Try rebooting and do `sudo apt-get update` and try installing them again. Also can you post your `lsb_release -a` output here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: Please do not use the same answer for multiple questions. Also, this answer is more like a comment, because you are asking a question in an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that @RolandiXor. I gave the same answer to two questions which were similar. I ll put this kind of suggestion in comment next time onwards...