# Why is the GCC 4.7 PPA not upgrading to 4.7.1?

Tags: gcc, g++

I would like to install from repository (without compilation from source) the latest g++ 4.7.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. I know I can install g++ 4.7.0 according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113291/installing-gcc-4-7) tutorial.

I have also found the g++ 4.7.1 exists in the same repository as mentioned in the tutorial [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test/+sourcepub/2554198/+listing-archive-extra). If there is newer version in the repository, why the previously installed version (4.7.0) is not updated when running the "Update Manager"? How do I install 4.7.1? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu (and especially Long Term Support version like 12.04) is not a rolling release distribution. Therefore the versions of stuff usually does not upgrade unless there is a serious reason to do that like major bug or security hole. If I want to use the latest version I should either use rolling release distro like Arch linux or compile stuff myself. Compiling GCC might be tricky though and should be performed with caution.