# How to use GCC 4.7 in place of 4.6?

Tags: 12.04, gcc, update-alternatives

So I'm working on a project and I wanted to use some C11 features for C. To use those features GCC 4.7 is required, so I went to synaptic and looked up 4.7, and I found the packages gcc-4.7-base so I installed it[1].

So now that gcc-4.7-base is installed I expected to be able to use 4.7, but no, when I do `gcc --version` it still shows 4.6.3 even more, when I try to directly call 4.7(via `/usr/bin/gcc-4.7`) it doesn't exist, though a `gcc-4.6` executable does exist.

How do I "activate" GCC 4.7? I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version), you do some crazy stuff with `update-alternatives`, but it doesn't work for me as the `gcc-4.7` executable doesn't actually exist on my machine.

Notes:
1. I also saw gcc-4.6-base, so I figured I'd uninstall it, but synaptic attempted to remove every package I had installed and install a Java runtime, so for obvious reason I decided not to remove it.

Answer (score 13):

The following worked for me.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.7 
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

[Source for reference](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, since the OP specifically said the `update-alternatives` route wouldn't work for them as they didn't have the gcc-4.7 binary available. Indeed, trying to follow the instructions in this answer after installing gcc-4.7-base results in the error: `update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 doesn't exist.`

Answer (score 0):

The `gcc` binary is in the `gcc-X.Y` package, not `gcc-X.Y-base`. The latter is a dependency of either `gcc-X.Y` or `libstdc++`.

Basically, you should simply install `gcc-4.7` and then either call it as `gcc-4.7` from your makefile, or use [`install-alternatives`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version) to make it the default.