# How do I set gcc 4.8 to be the default gcc?

Tags: 12.04, gcc

I'm trying to update to gcc 4.8.2. I have Ubuntu 12.04.

after this if I type *gcc -v* it says gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Next I typed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

Then I try to check the gcc version by typing `gcc -v` it says that my version didn't change and I still have gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

After typing `gcc-4.8 -v` I get 4.8 as the following:

```
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04)
```

Now my question turns into why isn't it finding gcc 4.8.2? How can I set it to use gcc 4.8 as the default when I use `gcc -v`?

Comment: `if I try 4.8.2 it cannot find it/ error occurs`, please post that error.

Comment: And also post the output of `apt-cache policy gcc` on your question.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ apt-cache policy gcc
gcc:
  Installed: 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  Candidate: 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$

Comment: Try `gcc-4.8 -v`, you need to be explicit

Comment: @user21839 Please put that information in your question not in the comments!

Comment: You need to tell Ubuntu to use 4.8 as the default, like this but for 4.8: http://askubuntu.com/questions/182027/how-to-use-gcc-4-7-in-place-of-4-6-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: If that works write it up as an answer to this question so we have one for 4.8!

Comment: @JorgeCastro no, there is no 4.8 version on available on his repos.

Comment: It's in there, he just needs to fix the alternatives to point to gcc-4.8

Comment: But `apt-cache policy gcc` shows `candidate:4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5`, which means he didn't installed an 4.8 version of gcc.

Comment: The package is `gcc-4.8`, not `gcc`