# I installed gcc-4.9 but when I type gcc -v I get 4.6.3

Tags: software-installation

I recently installed gcc-4.9 on Ubuntu 12.04 but when I type gcc -v it says gcc version 4.6.3.

The gcc 4.9 version was installed using the following command as root sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9

Comment: You will need to invoke it explicitly (i.e. `gcc-4.9` instead of `gcc`) or modify the `/usr/bin/gcc` symlink, either manually or by putting gcc into the `update-alternatives` mechanism.

Comment: GCC 4.9 is not available in Precise using the official repositories.
I assume you added a PPA of some sort.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/182027/how-to-use-gcc-4-7-in-place-of-4-6 to learn how to select the default GCC.

Comment: Muru-thanks for your informative comment. You are absolutely right that I added a PPA but my problem is that I cannot find the gcc-4.9 on my desktop. When I type which gcc-4.9 I get a blank. How do I find out where my gcc-4.9 got installed ?