# How to call a older version gcc?

Tags: gcc

My ubuntu is 14.04, the default gcc and g++ is 4.8, I installed gcc and g++ 4.4 manually, so how can I specify the older version of gcc to call when I compile a program?

Comment: How did you install it? Usually you just call `gcc-4.4`, `gcc-4.6`, etc., but depending on how you installed, that may not work.

Comment: I installed like this: sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4 g++4.4, so can I specify which gcc to use in make?

Comment: because when I make cuda 4.0 samples, this was always an error says: unsupported GNU version! gcc 4.5 and up are not supported!

Comment: Also related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/313288/how-to-use-multiple-instances-of-gcc http://askubuntu.com/questions/182027/how-to-use-gcc-4-7-in-place-of-4-6

Comment: I'd say you might be asking for problems as some of the bindings generated on the older versions of the compiler might not be compatible with the later operating system.  So things using shared object libraries might have difficulty.  Why not just use the latest version?

Comment: because I met a problem "unsupported GNU version!gcc 4.5 and up are not supported!" when i compiled my cuda sample using gcc 4.8, so I have to use a lower version