# How to activate gcc 4.7 version?

Tags: 12.04, gcc

I have gcc 4.6.3 installed:

```
gcc --version

gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

I have installed newer version:

```
apt-get install gcc-4.7
```

But i still get result "gcc 4.6.3" when I type `gcc --version`. How to fix it?

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and i have done

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because you have both versions installed, with 4.6 being treated as the default one.

You can explicitly choose which one to use.

```
$ gcc-4.7 --version
gcc-4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-22ubuntu4) 4.7.2
[...]

$ gcc-4.6 --version
gcc-4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-15ubuntu3) 4.6.3
[...]
```

The easiest way make `gcc-4.7` the default `gcc` is to move the symlink of `/usr/bin/gcc`:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 /usr/bin/gcc
```

Comment: How to set gcc-4.7 default?

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко Do you wish to just make `gcc-4.7` the default `gcc`, or would you rather easily switch `gcc` between `gcc-4.6` and `gcc-4.7`?

Comment: I probably need it because I get the following error message installing Webkit application fom source.

configure: error: Compiler GCC >= 4.7 or Clang >= 3.0 is required for C compilation

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко This makes sense. GCC 4.7 introduces support for C++0x standard, which may be required by new software.

Comment: I want to make gcc-4.7 the default gcc. Hope that helps

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко I have updated my answer.

Comment: Now i get gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-11precise2) 4.7.2 when type 
gcc --version. But webkit error remained.

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко Try explicitly prepending all `./configure`, `make` etc. commands with `CC="gcc-4.7"`, e.g. `CC="gcc-4.7" make`. Anyway, as you have correct `gcc --version`, this seems to be a separate problem with webkit compilation. Also, maybe you need to clear it's build cache (get a fresh copy of sources).

Comment: didn`t work. I should probably rise the question about webkit in separate thread. Thanks for answering this question anyway :)

Comment: Overwriting the `gcc` symlink is a bad idea, `gcc` should be the compiler with which most software on the system, especially the kernel, was build, having a different version could cause bugs which would be difficult to pinpoint. If a specific version of GCC is needed to compile a specific program, it should be defined in the relevant Makefiles (or whatever build system the program uses) using the `CC` variable (as @RafałCieślak correctly notes).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for installation of old version of gcc, then install directly from command line. For instance if you want install gcc-4.4.6, and latest available version is 4.7.3. If you type:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

then by default latest version will be installed. To install gcc-4.4.6, just type:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4
```

But still your default compiler is latest gcc. To remove latest gcc as default type:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc
```

Now making gcc-4.4.6 as default compiler (this is replacement of gcc by gcc-4.4.x), type:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 /usr/bin/gcc
```

Hope this will clarify above mentioned problem.

Answer (score -1):

please follow this instruction:
Build gcc (Here: version: 4.7.2)

```
tar -xf gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2
mkdir gcc-build
cd gcc-build
../gcc-4.7.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++
make -j 4
make install
make clean          (OPTIONAL)
cd ..
```

Currently, the self-check of the gcc is not working, so this step is omitted here.
Now you should check that the new compiler version 4.7.2 is called instead of the compiler used for the build process (here gcc-4.5.3). Enter the following commands:

```
gcc --version; g++ --version
```

The new compiler has been installed in `/usr/local/bin`. It is now the default compiler, because in the PATH variable `/usr/local/bin`  is before `/usr/bin`.