# Linux still compiles with gcc 4.8.4 after installing 4.7.3

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am trying to build a code from this website on linux. https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/segbench/ When I run gmake install in the directory (as instructed), I get the following error below telling me to use gcc 4.7.x.

```
Building with 'g++'.
Warning: You are using gcc version '4.8.4'. The version of gcc is not
supported. The version currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'. For a list of
currently supported compilers see:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release. 
Error using mex
In file included from
```

I have followed this thread to install gcc version 4.7.3 [How to activate gcc 4.7 version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269257/how-to-activate-gcc-4-7-version) and have verified that my version of gcc 4.7.3 by typing gcc -v.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7
sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 /usr/bin/gcc
```

So im not sure why its still trying to build with 4.8.4. Was hoping someone could help me out.

Comment: `g++` is not the same thing as `gcc` (well, not in this context, at least)

Comment: . . . you likely need to install the corresponding `g++-4.7.3` and either symlink that to `/usr/bin/g++` or (less drastically - and how I would recommend) simply set appropriate variables `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.7.3` and `CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.7.3`

Comment: Messing with the `gcc` symlink (et al.) is just asking for trouble.

Comment: hi steeldriver thanks for the help. I installed g++-4.7 then typed CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.7 but g++ -v still says gcc version 4.8.4 while gcc -v says gcc version 4.7.3