# How can I change "which gcc" directory?

Tags: gcc, symbolic-link

`gcc-4.8` is installed from build-essential.

I used `gcc-4.8` to build `gcc-4.7.4` from source, and put that 4.7 build in a folder called `/AntonProj1`

I have been able to change the symbolic link from the default gcc to the build in `/AntonProj1` via

```
rm /usr/bin/gcc

ln -s /AntonProj1/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc
```

So, while I can find the correct version (4.7.4) by doing `gcc-v`, I am still linked to `/usr/bin/gcc` when I ask `which gcc`

When I try something like:

```
ln -s /AntonProj1/bin/gcc /AntonProj1/tmp/gcc
```

I am no longer able to get the correct version doing `-v` and it is still looking in `/usr/bin/gcc` when I ask `which gcc` (it actually throws `bash: /usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory`)

How can I build a link to, for example, `/AntonProj1/tmp/gcc` so that I can use the `gcc` command to compile with my own build (`gcc-4.7.4`) instead of the default build?

Comment: `which` simply checks for executables on your `PATH` - it doesn't follow symlinks AFAIK. If you'd done `readlink -f $(which gcc)` you should have arrived at `/AntonProj1/bin/gcc`. However IMHO it would be cleaner to simply add `/AntonProj/bin` to the front of your `PATH`. It's not clear what you've done in the meantime to get `/usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory`

Comment: BTW why did you install gcc-4.7.4 from source at all? it seems to be available in the repositories up until at least Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Kind of duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/884576/linux-still-compiles-with-gcc-4-8-4-after-installing-4-7-3?rq=1, maybe?

Comment: Ah, ok. I will check the PATH settings. Thanks! (And I installed it from source for a personal challenge. I'm trying to build 40 or so projects from source; but, I wanted to build gcc from source first so I could use *that* compiler to build the others...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I did to fix things the way I was looking for them to be when I asked the question. I'm not sure if this is the best way; but, it's working for now:

**Setting up symbolic links:**

Remove existing links:

```
rm /usr/bin/gcc
rm /usr/bin/g++
```

Change name of default executibles because I want to run commands `gcc` and `g++`:

```
mv /AntonProj1/bin/gcc /AntonProj1/bin/gcc-4.7.4
mv /AntonProj1/bin/g++ /AntonProj1/bin/g++-4.7.4
```

Set new symbolic links:

```
ln -s /AntonProj1/bin/gcc-4.7.4 /AntonProj1/bin/gcc
ls -s /AntonProj1/bin/g++-4.7.5 /AntonProj1/bin/g++
```

Setting up PATH stuff:

```
export "PATH+=:/AntonProj1/bin"
```

While I'm not sure my method of setting up the path is ideal (it must not be since I have to add a path to any directory I'd like to run `gcc` or `g++` from), this easy export appends the correct path to the end of whatever path is already set... I can imagine setting it up in a profile.d or something; but, for my purposes it's OK as it is.

Comment: I discovered the way to do this permanently by setting the PATH by putting the export in the .profile file of the home directory:

`export "PATH=/AntonProj1/bin:/AntonProj1/share:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Of note here is that the new path should be at the beginning and not at the end...