# Cannot find -lgfortran

Tags: compiling, gcc, fortran, ld

I'm trying to install a package in R (package "ks"). It fails with error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
```

I've already installed the Ubuntu package build-essential:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I've also tried adding symbolic links:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 /usr/lib/libgfortran.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgfortran.so.3.0.0 /usr/lib/libgfortran.so
sudo ldconfig
```

I use gcc and g++ regularly, but haven't yet had reason to use gfortran.

I've seen others with this problem on gcc-4.7 (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2123821), so I wonder if this is from manually installing gcc-4.7. I followed the recipe from the accepted answer here [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113291/how-do-i-install-gcc-4-7) and here [here](https://superuser.com/questions/310809/how-can-i-update-gcc-to-the-latest-version-in-ubuntu-10-04/394811#394811).

Running `lsb_release -a` prints

> Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

and running `uname -r` prints

> 3.2.0-39-generic-pae

Can anyone offer advice for why `ld` doesn't work?

Comment: You tried to make symbolic links against *runtime* libraries, not the ones that linker wants (*.a dev libs). Looks like the path issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install gfortran. The error points out that the static lib for build-time linking is missing not the dynamic libs you tried to adjust.

Comment: When I try `sudo apt-get install gfortran`, I get `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`... Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, on my system I get for `dpkg -S /usr/lib/gcc/x86)64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgfortran.a` the answer that this is from the `gfortran-4.6` package. Gcc is looking for the .a file. If you installed another gcc version, the linker is looking inside a similarly named directory for libgfortran.a.

Comment: Looks like a valid answer.

Comment: Symbolic linking the 4.6 library for the 4.7 compiler might work. Also passing the correct path with `-L` (which is largely the same). If this fails you need to install the 4.7 version of gfortran from the ppa you used for gcc 4.7. What gfortran version do you have now?

Comment: I needed to use the same trick as installing gcc-4.7 to install gfortran-4.7.

Comment: I faced same error and eventually `~$ sudo apt-get install libgfortran-*` to install all versions to cope with it. these `sudo apt-get install r-cran-ks` very useful which can let us install through terminal :)

Answer (score 19):

What I did, I check on ubuntu if the versions of g++, gcc and gfortran are the same or not.

I guess it is better if you have all the three of same version.

```
# first check the versions:
gcc --version
g++ --version
gfortran --version

# If versions are different, then install:
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9 gfortran-4.9
```

For me this resolved all the issues which I was facing while installing "TTR" package in R using RStudio on Ubuntu.

If you further run into the issue `gfortran: command not found`, make sure that you have `/usr/bin/gfortran` linking to the actual version of `gfortran` you have installed (e.g. linking to `gfortran-4.9`):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gfortran gfortran /usr/bin/gfortran-11 70
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. None of the above solutions worked for me

Comment: I am on gcc 6.5, but the same methods solved the issue. Interestingly, same source: an obscure R package.

Comment: Yes, this was one best solution I could think of.

Comment: More generally: `apt install gfortran-<your GCC version>`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, my `gcc` and `g++` were 11.3.0 but `gfortran` not found. I installed `gfortran-11` since 11.3.0 and 11.3 did not exist

Comment: In my case:
 
`sudo update-alternatives --config g++`, 
`sudo update-alternatives --config gcc`

and choose the same version as `gfortran`

Answer (score 9):

A little more explanation to Cloud Oliver's answer.

Find out the gcc version currently being used through this command.

```
$sudo update-alternatives --config gcc

* 2            /usr/bin/gcc-4.7   60        manual mode
```

The entry with `*` tells which version of GCC is being used. Just press enter to keep the current settings.

If it prints "no alternatives for gcc", you might have to use this command to find out the version:

```
apt-cache policy gcc
```

1. `cd` to the right gcc directory (replace the version number with yours):

   ```
   cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/
   ```
2. You can search for `libgfortran.a` with the following command (optional). In my case it was present in the `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/` directory.

   ```
   find /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -name libgfortran.a
   ```
3. Create the symlink:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.a libgfortran.a
   ```

Comment: You should use the gfortran lib that matches the compiler instead of mixing versions. Manoj Kumar's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

```
cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.a libgfortran.a
```

Comment: Could you make it a little more verbose? Maybe a separate `cd` line at least?

Comment: Please add an explanation. People should never blindly run commands they find on the internet. So please also don't write them.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it for me! In my case it was `cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3` and then  `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.a libgfortran.a`