# apt-get: error loading libgcc_s.so.1

Tags: 12.04, apt, gcc

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, 64-bit, with gcc 4.6.3

I want to update gcc to 4.7, and do as the link said:

[How do I install gcc 4.7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113291/how-do-i-install-gcc-4-7)

But I got error:

```
Fetched 14.0 MB in 18s (767 kB/s)                                    
(Reading database ... 205536 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libgcc1 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 (using .../libgcc1_1%3a4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libgcc1 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1', which is also in package gcc-4.6 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so I remove gcc 4.6:

```
sudo apt-get remove gcc-4.6
sudo apt-get update
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now `apt-get, vi` can't work any more.

Answer (score 16):

This isn't a genuine fix, but a workaround.

The correct course of action is to install `gcc-multilib`, with `apt-get install gcc-multilib`

Comment: This helped like charme on Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5!
Why is it a workaround?

Answer (score 5):

I copy a `libgcc_s.so.1` from other computer to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Then the problem solved.

I install gcc-4.7 again, it succeed.

Answer (score 3):

installing gcc-multilib is the only thing that helped for me, i am running ubuntu 15. Thank you!

Comment: Ubuntu 16 and this worked for me as well

Answer (score 2):

(I stumbled upon the same issue years later, and nobody except [Aylwyn Lake](https://askubuntu.com/a/410417/1144685) addresses the original situation where **`apt-get` does not work**)

So, if you face this error message when running `apt`:

> apt: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

you can still hopefully bring back `libgcc_s.so.1`. Here are two solutions:

- install a `.deb` package with **dpkg** instead of `apt`. You should find such a package on [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=libgcc_s.so.1) - be sure to select the right version. Then run `sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb`
- find this file somewhere else on your harddrive and place a copy in the folder `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.
  You can search all across your disk with the command `find / -name "libgcc_s.so.1"`.
  You may also find this file on a live or installation device (CD, USB stick) if you have one

Answer (score 0):

I follow `iaeiou` 's suggesstion and solve this problem successfully for my Jetson-tx2 (arm64 system) with the help of my another PC.

First, I download the  `libgcc1-dbg_6.3.0-18+deb9u1_arm64.deb` from this website

```
http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-6/
```

Then I use `scp` to sent this deb package to my Jetson-tx2

```
/home/my_usrname $  scp /home/my_usrname/libgcc1_6.3.0-18+deb9u1_arm64.deb tx2-usrname@192.168.1.195:/home/usrname
```

Finally I switch to Jetson-tx2 and install this deb package

```
/home/tx2-usrname $  sudo dpkg -i libgcc1_6.3.0-18+deb9u1_arm64.deb
```

ps: maybe you also need to download the `gcc-6-base` as the dependence of the `libgcc1-xxxx.deb`, which is in https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gcc-6-base or http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-6/ and use the same method.

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to make any of the other solutions work; however, I did get this resolved.

Running the find command above, I was able to locate 32-bit copies of the file but came up empty in /lib/ and /usr/lib/. After some digging around I came across this:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libgcc_s.so.1

```
/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 gcc-snapshot
/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1   gcc-snapshot
/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/libx32/libgcc_s.so.1  gcc-snapshot
```

This was the first package I saw with a reference to this file outside of /lib32, /libx32. So with nothing else to lose, I gave this a try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-snapshot
```

Still broken; however, now I can find these:

```
$ sudo find / -name "libgcc_s.so.1"
...
/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/libx32/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/libx32/libgcc_s.so.1
...
```

So there it is, `/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/lib/libgcc_s.so.1` after adding this directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` I tried again and it worked...

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/lib
```

Lastly I just copied the file `/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/lib/libgcc_s.so.1` to `/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1` and all seems good.