# Having problem installing Matlab on ubuntu

Tags: matlab

i have problems installing matlab, while installing it requires installing gcc compiler and java developer kit and gfortran , i've installed all of them but the installation still won't complete :( ,please help me to solve this problem :( thanks

---

The result of running `java -version`

```
java version "1.6.0_24" 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2) 
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

---

The result of running `gcc --version`

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc. 
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO 
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the results of typing `java -version` and `gcc --version` into a command prompt?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
-------------------------------------------------------

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Matlab probably wants the Oracle JDK as opposed to the OpenJDK

Comment: sorry to ask dumb questions but i'm new to linux , what command should i use ? sudo apt-get install what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html?sec=glnxa64) states that, for Java, matlab requires two things, neither of which your system has:

1. JDK 1.7 (You have 1.6)
2. The Oracle JDK (you have the OpenJDK) (Note: It doesn't explicitly state this, but it links to the Oracle website)

You can fix both in one step by following the instructions in [this askUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/284690)

For gcc, it wants versoin 4.7 or higher. You have 4.6. See [this askUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113291/how-do-i-install-gcc-4-7) on how to solve that.

I didn't ask for your gfortran version, and I'm unsure of how to get it. Verify that your gfortran is at least 4.7 as well.

Comment: Just edited it with regards to gcc; you'll need to update that as well

Comment: gfortran version : GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
yes i read your edited comment , thank you :)

Comment: You'll need to update gfortran as well: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gfortran

Comment: i don't know which one should i install for gfortran :(:(:( , my operating system is ubuntu 12.04 lts  32bit , sorry, can you help me please :(  (gcc and g++ and jdk are up to date now, i don't know which one should i install for gfortran)

Comment: Try just doing `sudo apt-get install gfortran`

Comment: sorry it's the last question :D , i've installed it, but when i run the command gfortran --version, the version is still 4.6 , how can i configure the version in use and select the new version ?

Comment: What  version of Ubuntu are you using? What does `apt-cache policy gfortran` show you?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04  ,  Installed: 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  Candidate: 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: According to [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gfortran) 4.7 isn't available on 12.04... and a quick google search doesn't get me anything. Maybe try asking another question on how to install it, or consider upgrading to 14.04